# run time errors in starting weka 3.7.13

Tags: java, weka

I just installed Weka 3.7.13 on Windows 8.1 64bit. When I am starting the apps, it give a run time error "Could not locate default config file". I am using the same application for long time but today it start this error. 
The run time error that I received is

```
    [31-10-2015 15:20:00] [Warning] [Load Config] Could not locate default config file.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: m_simplePanel
    org.openml.weka.gui.OpenmlSetupModePanel.<init>(OpenmlSetupModePanel.java:43)
    org.openml.weka.gui.OpenmlExperimenter.<init>(OpenmlExperimenter.java:46
    )
    org.openml.weka.gui.OpenmlExperimenter.<init>(OpenmlExperimenter.java:75
    )
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source
    )
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    weka.gui.beans.PluginManager.getPluginInstance(PluginManager.java:329)
    weka.gui.GUIChooser.<init>(GUIChooser.java:1051)
    weka.gui.GUIChooser.createSingleton(GUIChooser.java:268)
    weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:1690)

    at org.openml.weka.gui.OpenmlSetupModePanel.<init>(OpenmlSetupModePanel.java:43)
    at org.openml.weka.gui.OpenmlExperimenter.<init>(OpenmlExperimenter.java:46)
    at org.openml.weka.gui.OpenmlExperimenter.<init>(OpenmlExperimenter.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at weka.gui.beans.PluginManager.getPluginInstance(PluginManager.java:329
    )
    at weka.gui.GUIChooser.<init>(GUIChooser.java:1051)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooser.createSingleton(GUIChooser.java:268)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:1690)
```

Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

It may be a [problem with OpenML package](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Error-in-starting-Weka-Reg-td35824.html) (the same happened to me).

Search in `wekafiles/packages` for a folder called `OpenmlWeka` and delete it. I'm not sure where it is on windows but I guess that `wekafiles` folder should be at your user's home. Then you should be able to run weka as usual.

If later you need to use OpenML you can reinstall it from the weka's package manager.